# Robolectric 3.0 with Facebook sdk 4.0

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, robolectric, android-testing

I'm trying to get my tests working with `Robolectric.setupActivity(LoginActivity.class);` where my class uses the facebook sdk 4.0 for login. Even though I added `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);` as below:

```
public class LoginActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            ...
        }
    }
```

I get the following error in my tests:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException at LoginActivityTest.java:32
        Caused by: com.facebook.FacebookSdkNotInitializedException at LoginActivityTest.java:32
```

Here is my test class:

```
@RunWith(CustomRobolectricRunner.class)
@Config(emulateSdk = 21, reportSdk = 21, constants = BuildConfig.class)
public class LoginActivityTest {

    private Button loginButton;
    private ShadowActivity loginActivityShadow;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception
    {
        LoginActivity activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(LoginActivity.class);

        loginButton = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
        loginActivityShadow = Shadows.shadowOf(activity);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldStartFacebookActivityWhenLoginButtonIsClicked()
    {
        Intent intent = loginActivityShadow.getNextStartedActivity();
        loginButton.performClick();
        //assertThat(activity, new StartedMatcher(com.facebook.LoginActivity.class));
    }

}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to call `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);` before you call `setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);`.

Comment: Is it the same error? Can you debug and see that the sdkInitialize call is being hit. If you're using PowerMockito as well, it won't work, because the ClassLoader that PowerMockito uses is different than the one that Robolectric uses. So the first call will initialize the class in the PowerMockito ClassLoader, and the second would look at Robolectric ClassLoader.

Comment: Same error as before, I'm not using Powermockito but I'm using mockito. The error is as follow: `Caused by: null
 at com.facebook.internal.Validate.sdkInitialized(Validate.java:99)
 at com.facebook.FacebookSdk.getApplicationId(FacebookSdk.java:660)
 at com.facebook.FacebookRequestError.getErrorClassification(FacebookRequestError.java:429)`

Comment: Follow https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/#androidstudio  You have to add the app id in your test apps' AndroidManifest.xml, you also need to declare FacebookActivity. Similar to: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/Scrumptious/AndroidManifest.xml#L47-L51

Comment: That's what I did. I also added the FacebookActivity to the manifest. It works perfectly in normal build mode. But it crashes when I run `./gradlew assembleDebug test`

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/FacebookSdk.java#L125  If you hit it twice, two different class loaders are loading the function. In that case I don't know how to fix it.  Also add a breakpoint here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/FacebookSdk.java#L156 and make sure that's hit. Finally put a breakpoint here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/FacebookSdk.java#L603-L605 and see if that's behaving right.

Comment: Working fine now with ver 4.0.1, looks like it was an internal bug